# Triggering re-build on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to trigger a re-build of the jenkins builds? I'm thinking about something [like this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin).

The reason I would like to do this is that I am releasing a package which runs fine in the pre-release tests, but fails on Jenkins (see also [my other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/235809/enforcing-catkin-commands-for-jenkins-builds/) about this). Now I'd like to be able to test this particular case locally.

I can apply the fixes in my repo and then re-run bloom-release to push to the release repository. I don't increase the version, and skip the part about the PR to rosdistro. This causes all packages which have failed so far to re-build (they failed because they depend on the faulty package which needs fixing). However the faulty package itself has built fine, so a jenkins re-build is not triggered for it - with the result of having all depending packages fail again, even though the cause of error has been fixed in the release repository.

In my case, I just forgot to set a flag needed for jenkins build in my cmake file. Is it necessary to increase version and do a full bloom bloom-release (incl. PR), even if changes are tiny, in order to trigger a re-build of a particular jenkins project? Or is there an easier way to do this? I don't want to flood the system with silly version increases, I'd prefer to test this locally before I re-release the package. Is there a standard way to do this?

Thanks for your help,
Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235810/triggering-re-build-on-jenkins/) by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-06-01**:
Can you please clarify which job you are referring to. A devel job or a sourcedeb / binarydeb job?

**Comment by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on 2016-06-01**:
One example was [arm_components_name_manager](http://build.ros.org/job/Ibin_uT64__arm_components_name_manager__ubuntu_trusty_amd64__binary/). It needs the baselib_binding package, which had built fine. I wanted to re-trigger building baselib_binding (after only setting a flag to true in cmakelists)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-06-01**:
http://build.ros.org/view/Idev/job/Idev__jb_common_libs__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/ should be the job since that repo contains the package of the referenced binary job (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/c9164b251da44df2aaa7dd928f596f29ff0da74b/indigo/distribution.yaml#L4085-L4105).

**Comment by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on 2016-06-01**:
Ok, that's great to know, I'll try this. So far the devel branches have built fine, but maybe I have missed something there. I'll re-release the package with the fixes - it's anyway only required for the first release of the package, until things are fixed, so it's not a huge concern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I binary job builds a released package. Therefore it requires you to make a new release to trigger it again. You might want to use a devel job which is being triggered on new commits to your upstream repo.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0